# How can I make Emil show up at the Resistance Camp?

Tags: nier-automata

I've been trying for a while now to get Emil to show up at the Resistance Camp so that I can buy his weapons and advanced crafting components. So far, the only way I've made any progress towards that is by following [this guide](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/168677-nier-automata/75496305). It basically recommends alternating interacting with him and completing story events in chapter 14-1. By doing that, I got him to take a longer route that passes through the crater and by both the factory and his original area. I also got the described email from him, plus another email. But he never seems to go near the Resistance camp, even if I teleport out of the city and back, or walk out and back, or save and reload. Is there anything else I need to do to make him go near the Resistance camp.

If it matters, I already

> fought him and got the Emil Heads weapon

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Technically, there is not a way to *make* Emil drive by the Resistance Camp; it's random where he spawns, but that route is definitely less common than the one in front of the Desert Zone. All you can do is make him respawn and hope he shows up on the route that takes him by the Resistance Camp. I personally reloaded the area repeatedly until he was in the right place, but according to [this video](https://youtu.be/vi_fF1b06m) I found, you can make him respawn *without* reloading the area, which vastly reduces the amount of time you will spend trying to get him to show up by the Resistance Camp.

The video says to do this in Chapter 7-1.

The steps laid out in the video are:

- Finish the Forest Kingdom chapter
- Talk to Emil at least once
- Run (don't fast travel) to the abandoned commercial facility
- Run about halfway across the bridge back to the City Ruins and check on Emil's location.
- Run back into the abandoned commercial facility if he is not on the correct route.

Repeat the last two steps until he shows up.

It's worth mentioning that you need to shoot Emil at the right time for him to land in front of the Resistance Camp, as there have been numerous reports of Emil not selling the good stuff even though he was driving along the correct route. The proper timing of this is also included in that video around the 3:10 mark.

Comment: I wish I'd seen this video when I was trying to get Emil to show up in the right place. I just reloaded the area over and over until he was in the right place...

Comment: This worked for me. Specifically, after the steps I had already taken, running across the bridge to the commercial facility and back got him to spawn near the Resistance Camp.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree, the best method for me is using the elevator you use to go down to the large underground cave system and see emil, just inside the broken white pipe. Said pipe is round the city ruins where the huge white tower is at the end of the game. (See other sources) You just go down the elevator and go back up again and it resets the whole area. This worked best for me playing as A2 but that may be bias on my part as I play as A2 a lot and have not repeated this test as 9S or 2B. Hope this helped recent players looking for an updated solution